# Which is worse, not giving our all to know what's going on or not giving our all to share or communicate that which we have learned?

Tags: life, death

I gave my all to know and understand but have not given my all to share or communicate that which I have learned and understood. In which state am I the worst, being content in ignorance or selfish in possession? I understand we will all make it, in whatever way we may define making it, until we don't and after that it's out of our hands.

Comment: I fail to see why this should be a dichotomy. Why does it have to be in terms of "giving all"? Isn't there like a middle ground, that is more fruitfull?

Comment: To cazanox, none of us mere humans give our all in pursuit as we must eat, sleep, and eliminate bodily waste. I mean all of the intent we can muster.

Answer (score 1):

Each and every human is wishing for contentment in life.  It is a great thing.  You needn't worry even if the contentment is because of ignorance.

On the other hand, a learned man if he is selfish, we can make sure that he hasn't learned the actual thing that is to be acquired through learning (because the required behavioral change is not seen in him).  He is egocentric.

So, being selfish in possession is worse than being content in ignorance. [That is, not giving our all to share or communicate that which we have learned is worse.]

You can read some explanations (that support this) in the Bhagavad Gita.

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/10

Comment: Thank you for your answer mr thought. I worry myself in hope for the discontent of humanity.

Comment: Sharing is a good remedy for many problems now we are facing.  It can do wonders.